# ImageButton.setOnClickListener -> Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

In Android Studio

Simply adding the following code to MainActivity.Java causes the error. @override is also underlined red and there is an issue with "onClick(View view)" where the second view is red?

```
ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, dexter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
...
}
```

no `View.` in front of the listener.

Comment: Thanks, changed that.

The .setOnClickListener is still not resolved